# Regex simplification with subgroups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Can this be simplified to avoid repetitions? It would be better to not have duplicate groups.

Here is the structured output from my regex with reputations:

```
^(?<Version>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))(?!.*[\.-]$)(?:(?<IsReleaseVersion>-)(?:(?:(?<RArea1>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<RStep1>[\d]+)\.(?<RHash1>[\.\da-z]+)\.(?<RCiId1>\d{1,4}))|(?:(?<RArea2>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<RStep2>[\d]+)\.(?<RId2>[\.\da-z]+))|(?:(?<RArea3>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<RStep3>[\d]+))|(?:(?<RArea4>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+))))?(?:(?<IsBuildVersion>\+)(?:(?:(?<BArea1>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<BStep1>[\d]+)\.(?<BId2>[\.\da-z]+)\.(?<BCiId2>\d{1,4}))|(?:(?<BArea2>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<BStep2>[\d]+)\.(?<BId2>[\.\da-z]+))|(?:(?<BArea3>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<BStep3>[\d]+))|(?:(?<BArea4>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+))))?$
```

Here is the input text:

```
<Version>: (A)=1.0.1 (B)=1.0.1 (C)=1.0.1 (D)=1.0.1 (E)=1.0.1 (F)=1.0.1 (1): (A)=1 (B)=1 (C)=1 (D)=1 (E)=1 (F)=1 (2): (A)=0 (B)=0 (C)=0 (D)=0 (E)=0 (F)=0 (3): (A)=1 (B)=1 (C)=1 (D)=1 (E)=1 (F)=1 <IsReleaseVersion>: (A)=null (B)=null (C)=null (D)=null (E)=null (F)=- <IsBuildVersion>: (A)=+ (B)=+ (C)=+ (D)=+ (E)=null (F)=null <Area>: (A)=beta (B)=beta (C)=beta (D)=beta (E)=null (F)=beta <Step>: (A)=1 (B)=1 (C)=1 (D)=null (E)=null (F)=1 <Id>: (A)=abcd1234 (B)=abcd1234 (C)=null (D)=null (E)=null (F)=abcd1234 <CiId>: (A)=0001 (B)=null (C)=null (D)=null (E)=null (F)=null
```

I hope anyone can help me!

Comment: You should also include the text you're using this on and the result/expected result and captured groups

Comment: The input is the text you're using this regex against.

Comment: When the input is  
(A)= 1.0.1+beta.1.abcd1234.0001  
(B)= 1.0.1+beta.1.abcd1234  
(C)= 1.0.1+beta.1  
(D)= 1.0.1+beta  
(E)= 1.0.1  
(F)= 1.0.1-beta.1.abcd1234

Comment: <Version>: (A)=1.0.1 (B)=1.0.1 (C)=1.0.1 (D)=1.0.1 (E)=1.0.1 (F)=1.0.1  
(1): (A)=1 (B)=1 (C)=1 (D)=1 (E)=1 (F)=1  
(2): (A)=0 (B)=0 (C)=0 (D)=0 (E)=0 (F)=0  
(3): (A)=1 (B)=1 (C)=1 (D)=1 (E)=1 (F)=1  
<IsReleaseVersion>: (A)=null (B)=null (C)=null (D)=null (E)=null (F)=-  
<IsBuildVersion>: (A)=+ (B)=+ (C)=+ (D)=+ (E)=null (F)=null  
<Area>: (A)=beta (B)=beta (C)=beta (D)=beta (E)=null (F)=beta  
<Step>: (A)=1 (B)=1 (C)=1 (D)=null (E)=null (F)=1  
<Id>: (A)=abcd1234 (B)=abcd1234 (C)=null (D)=null (E)=null (F)=abcd1234  
<CiId>: (A)=0001 (B)=null (C)=null (D)=null (E)=null (F)=null

Comment: Your regex has a duplicate `<BId2>` I ran it against the input text after replacing the first `<BId2>` with `<BId1>` and it produced no results. Also, what programming language or program are you using this in?

Comment: Oh, sorry that was a typo. I use that regex in c#/.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg, you've made a fine mess :) I've just focused on this part:

```
((?:(?:(?<RArea1>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<RStep1>[\d]+)\.(?<RHash1>[\.\da-z]+)\.(?<RCiId1>\d{1,4}))|
(?:(?<RArea2>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<RStep2>[\d]+)\.(?<RId2>[\.\da-z]+))|
(?:(?<RArea3>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)\.(?<RStep3>[\d]+))|
(?:(?<RArea4>[\da-z][\.\da-z-]+)))
```

This could be rewritten as:

```
(?:(?<Area>[\da-z]+)(?:\.(?<Step>[\d]+)(?:\.(?<Hash>[\da-z]+)(?:\.(?<CiId>\d{1,4}))?)?)?)
```

Simply nest your conditionals.

See it in [action](http://regex101.com/r/lX5vI2).